# How to embed the broadcast from the camera in the container in Codename1?

Tags: java, video-capture, codenameone

In my application there is a video button. Here's the code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onGUI1_Button1Action (Component c, ActionEvent event){


            try {
                String value = Capture.captureVideo();
                if (value != null) {
                    final Form previous = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
                    Form preview = new Form("Preview");
                    preview.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
                    if (!value.startsWith("file:/")) {
                        value = "file:/" + value;
                    }
                    pl.setDataSource(value);
                    preview.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, pl);
                    preview.setBackCommand(new Command("Back") {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            previous.showBack();
                        }
                    });
                    preview.show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(ex);
                Dialog.show("Error", "" + ex, "OK", null);
            }
        }
```

I picked up this code from github. I don't want to broadcast the video on full screen. I need a video from camera was built into some container. That container must cover only part of the screen. I have built a GUI and put a container(Media Player) into some part of screen. 
How to change the code for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a camera view finder right into your app with a new cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

Overlaying native widgets has been possible for a year or so by now.

Original answer which was correct when it was written is below:

Embedding camera or overlaying component on the preview screen is not yet available in codename one.

This could be done using native interface with peer component. Have a look at how Native map was implemented [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps)

Comment: In other words, to open the native camera, the application need to turn down. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: That's partially correct, native camera is opened but overlayed on your app.

Comment: FYI this is now possible, I updated the answer with newer developments

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thank you. This is great news. The link to a demo on the GitHub CameraKit is incorrect though.

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed now.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I tried the cn1lib on iPhone and there's no camera permission and the app is crashing.

Comment: You need to run this once in the simulator and it will setup the `ios.NSCameraUsageDescription` for you. If you don't do that you will need to make sure you have that build hint.

Comment: That build hint is added but still crashing.